# Calculating Using Conditional Distribution

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be the minimum and $Y$ be the maximum of $3$ digits picked at random without replacement from $\{0, 1, 2, \cdots, 9\}$. Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

**Without using Conditional Distribution:**

Since $3$ digits are picked without replacement, it follows the multivariate hypergeometric distribution so...

$\binom{1}{1}$ ways to pick the minimum $X$.

$\binom{y-x-1}{1}$ ways to pick the middle digit.

$\binom{1}{1}$ ways to pick the maximum $Y$

$\binom{10}{3}$ ways to pick any $3$ digit combination.

I have $$P(X = x, Y= y) = \frac{\binom{1}{1} \binom{y-x-1}{1} \binom{1}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{y-x-1}{120}$$

**Using Conditional Distribution:**

$$P(X = x, Y= y) = P(X = x)P(Y = y | X = x) = \frac{\binom{1}{1} \binom{9-x}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}} \cdot \frac{\binom{y-x-1}{1} \binom{1}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$ ?

Reasonings:

$\binom{1}{1}$ ways to pick the minimum$X$.

$\binom{9-x}{2}$ ways to pick the remaining $2$ digits in $P(X = x)$.

$\binom{10}{3}$ ways to pick any $3$ digit combination.

Since we are given $X = x$ in $P(Y = y | X = x)$, we only need to pick $2$ digits.

$\binom{y-x-1}{1}$ ways to pick the middle digit in $P(Y = y | X = x)$.

$\binom{1}{1}$ ways to pick the maximum $Y$.

$\binom{10}{3}$ ways to pick any $3$ digit combination.

But those two answers aren't equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional probability $P(Y = y | X = x)$ is the ratio of number of ways to chose 3 digits such that $Y=y$ among all ways with $X=x$. The number of ways when $X=x$ is $\binom{9-x}{2}\binom{1}{1}$, therefore 
$$P(Y = y | X = x)=\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{y-x-1}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{9-x}{2}\binom{1}{1}}.$$

And the answers coincide.

Comment: Ah thanks! $\binom{9-x}{2}$ instead of $\binom{10}{3}$ for the denominator of $P(Y=y|X=x)$